# maven, ant, or gradle plugin to execute cygwin cygpath?

Tags: maven, ant, gradle, cygwin, cygpath

Does anyone know of a maven, ant, or gradle plugin that supports invoking cygpath?  The cygpath utilities knows how to convert Windows filesystem paths (c:\dev) to cygwin/unix style file paths (/cygdrive/c/dev).

I've searched the internet but didn't find anything.  The closest is this jenkins plugin (https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/jenkins/cygpath+plugin).

Context:
I'm trying to automate creating an omniORB maven artifact from the omniORB source tarball.  One of the first things I have to do is patch the omniORB source with filesystem paths that match our development environment.  On every developer's machine we have an environment variable the specifies the location of their maven repo e.g. c:\mvrepo.  The omniORB Windows binaries are built with cygwin.  I need to set the omniORB makefile to locate some dependencies from c:\mvnrepo\some-dependency but with a cywin-style path /cygdrive/mvnrepo/some-depenendency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cant vouch for it a I haven't used it or looked at it closely but here is a gradle plugin that might be of use: https://github.com/derianto/Gradle-Cygwin-Toolkit-Plugin

In any case, since gradle scripts are written in groovy it should be fairly easy to just code your own solution into your build script if you have to.